# How do i add class to parent from selected element in pure JS parentNode is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent

so hello i am trying to add class that for element that passes all selectors
this is my current code

```
document.querySelectorAll('.inner p .align_center').parentNode.classList.add('center_text')
```

which uhh should work, i am trying to translate this jquery code

```
$(".inner p .align_center").parent().addClass('center_text')
```

but i get .parentNode is undefined in the console why? i selected child of p with class of .alignt-center and i want to add class to that p element, or is there easier way of doing the same thing? what am i doing wrong

Comment: yes, very much thanks, didnt know it sorts it in array, didnt had to downvote it tho but thanks in t he end

Comment: Np. Yes downvote is mine, but you could have been wrong, never assume that around here. And I will explain it. This question is answered at least 5 times a day here on SO. And if you have looked at documentation yourself of usage, you would have found the answer easily.

Comment: btw if you excpet just one element just use `document.querySelector`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('.inner p .align_center');
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].parentNode.classList.add('center_text');
}
```

just had to treat querySelectorAll as a array instead of single element